# Comparing database stringvalue with new stringvalue

Tags: php, database, compare, contacts

Here is what I'm trying to do: When user adds a contact to his list, the number of this contact gets run by with the numbers in the database and it gives feedback if the user is already in the database or not. Right now I always get back "User is in database" even though he isn't. Then again I'm not that well acquainted with php. I changed the code a bit again, now it doesn't work at all, because it doesn't like the part

```
$number = ($_GET["number"] from $DB_Table);
```

Full code

```
<?php
$DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "db";
$DB_User = "user";
$DB_Pass = "pw";
$DB_Table = "contacts";

$number = ($_GET["number"] from $DB_Table);

$fnumber = ($_GET["fnumber"]);

if ($number == $fnumber) {
    echo "This user is already in database";
} else {
echo "This user isn't in the database"; 
}

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die    (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: dont you think you are executing a wrong query that too before connecting to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually see you executing the database query. You could do something like this:

```
<?php

    $DB_HostName = "localhost";
    $DB_Name = "db";
    $DB_User = "user";
    $DB_Pass = "pw";
    $DB_Table = "contacts";

    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die (mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    $fnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["fnumber"]);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $DB_Table WHERE Something = '$fnumber'", $con);

    if ($result) {
        // Check the number of rows in the result set
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo "This user is already in database";
        }

        else echo "This user isn't in the database";
    }

    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, but the weird things is, it gives the following error Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /myserver/usercheck.php on line 9 - line 9 is     $fnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["fnumber"]);
Without it the connection works, but defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: I apologize, that was a mistake by me. You will need to move that line below where the database connection is initialized. I have corrected this in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid PHP code: `$number = ($_GET["number"] from $DB_Table);`

`$_GET["number"]` represents the value of the "`number`" parameter that you find in the url of your page.

Example: `http://example.com/index.php?number=7`   so `$_GET["number"]` is 7.

In your code, `$DB_Table` is a just a string ("`contact`") and "`from`" does not fit there using php syntax.

```
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

is valid PHP but you are not doing anything with what you get from the database. I suggest you at least take a look at this tutorial [php mysql select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)